# how to update custom attributes of user in aws cognito

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm integrating the stripe into the MERN app. On the stripe webhook call, I need to update the user custom attributes (Cognito). Is there any possible way to find the user using email in the pool and update its custom attributes?

I have tried **(function:listUsers)** this code to get the user but it doesn't provide the custom variables of the user.

```
const params = {
  UserPoolId: AWS_POOL_ID,
  AttributesToGet: ["email"],
};
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  AWS.config.update({
    region: AWS_REGION,
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_PUBLIC,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_ACCESS_SECRET,
  });
  const cognitoIdentityServiceProvider =
    new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
  cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.listUsers(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("cognito err::", err);
      reject(err);
    } else {
      console.log("cognito data:", data);
      resolve(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Response:

```
[
    {
      Username: '15a2-c98c-43a5-63c',
      Attributes: [
  { Name: 'email', Value: 'abc@gmail.com' }
],
      UserCreateDate: 2021-12-02T11:33:37.561Z,
      UserLastModifiedDate: 2021-12-02T11:35:24.956Z,
      Enabled: true,
      UserStatus: 'CONFIRMED'
    },
    {
      Username: '15ff633f-41faa9',
      Attributes: [
  { Name: 'email', Value: 'abc@gmail.com' }
],,
      UserCreateDate: 2021-09-17T14:37:12.943Z,
      UserLastModifiedDate: 2021-09-18T04:08:25.443Z,
      Enabled: true,
      UserStatus: 'CONFIRMED'
    }
]
```

**but I need to get and update the custom variables**
**only email available for finding user**

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in `email` in the `AttributesToGet` property in the parameters passed to the call to list the user. Based on [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html), if that array is not included, all attributes will be returned, including the custom attributes from Cognito, which should have the prefix of `custom:`.

You will also be able to update the user's custom attributes using [this function.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateUserAttributes.html)

Comment: Links expire over time. Can you provide the relevant information from those links as part of your answer?